# Is flux a function of (relative) velocity?

Tags: vector-fields

Consider a 3D space, where there is a field (electric, magnetic, whatever).

The field is $-c_1\hat k$, where $a$ is a positive constant, such that the field is constant everywhere towards the negative z-direction.

Consider a plane in the field, where $z=-x+c_2, 0<z<1, -c_3<y<c_3, 0<c_3$.

If the plane is moving towards the positive x-direction at a velocity $v(t)=f(t)\hat i$, is the flux through the plane going to be affected by the velocity of it?

Comment: You say "electric, magnetic, whatever", but in fact the answer depends very much on whether it's electric, magnetic, or whatever.

Comment: If the field is constant then would translation of your surface change the flux? Also are you asking about flux values or the rate of change of flux? Are you asking about explicit or implicit dependence?

Comment: Does the type of field matter? say if it is a vector field? Assuming that the field is constant and does not get affected by the movements of the plane. Does the flux value through the plane change?

Comment: If the field is constant then the flux is independent of where you are in space. So why would moving the surface change the flux?

Comment: I am just wrapping my head around it, since when I move, by relative motions, doesn't the flux look different to an observer on the plane?

Comment: No. Since the field is uniform every spatial coordinate gives the same flux. So no matter how you move through space the flux won't change. Now things do get tricky if you want to consider SR with electric and magnetic fields, but it seems like you are uninterested in that.

Comment: slightly off topic… an interesting thought came to mind. So if a person (assume shape doesn't change) runs through a rain (assume constant rain density), rain per unit time hitting him shouldn't change no matter how fast one runs (:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85429/discussion-between-aaron-stevens-and-nayfaan).

Answer (score 1):

Since the field is constant. The flux is equal to the projection of area on a plane perpendicular to the field and the magnitude of the field.

Thus, in this case, the flux will change only if the orientation of the plane relative to the direction of field changes.

So, the final answer is that the flux does not depend on the velocity in this case. However, it does depend on the orientation.